# Liferay Web Content Template : How to find out if image has been set?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, velocity, freemarker, liferay-velocity

I have created a Liferay Web Content Structure and Template.
This Structure contains an image that can or can not be set.
If the image is not set then I do not want to render an IMG tag.

How can I determine in my template if the picture is set / present ?

Best regards,

Daniel

Comment: Can you tell the type of ADT you have created?

Comment: Also can you show the template code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your field is called `imageField` you can do it like this with *Velocity*:

```
#if ($imageField.data != "")
  <img src="$imageField.data">
#end
```

(For *Freemarker* you can do a similar test)

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer of Tobias, you could also use the `$validator.isNull()` from velocity for null / not null value(s).

Sample code snippet:

```
#if (!$validator.isNull($imageField.data) && $imageField.data != "")
  <img src="$imageField.data">
#end
```

HTH